# WPF - How to move a UIElement dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, uielement

I have an ellipse inside a grid and I want to move the ellipse.

I have tried to use `RenderTransform.Transform()` and `TranslatePoint()` but nothing happened, on the latter I tried to set the parameter `relativeTo` to the ellipse and to grid but I get no movement nor exceptions in either case.

*Attempts:*

```cs
ellipse.RenderTransform.Transform(position);
//or
ellipse.TranslatePoint(position, grid);
//or
ellipse.TranslatePoint(position, ellipse);
```

What should I use to move the ellipse in my scenario?

Edit: On Xamarin I use the `TranslationY` property that allows me to do what I want, the docs tell me to use `TranslateTransform` but I dont understand how to use it.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. The typical approach for absolute positioning would be to put the Ellipse in a Canvas and set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties. You could also assign a TranslateTransform to the Ellipse's RenderTransform property. You should however read documentation first. And perhaps an introductory book where all the basics are explained.

Comment: thanks, TranslateTransform was what i needed but i didnt realize i had to assign to the render transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assign a `TranslateTransform` to the Ellipse's `RenderTransform` property

*Thanks Clemens to point that out in the comment section*

```cs
myUIElement.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(50,50);
```

*Offsets the UIElement 50 units right and down*

If its required to move several times its possible to use `X` and `Y` properties of `TranslateTransform`.

```cs
TranslateTransform position = new();

public void MoveRight(double _x)
{
   position.X += _x;
   myUIElement.RenderTransform = position;
}
```

*`MoveRight()` offsets the UIElement x axis by `_x` units*

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Ellipse` in a `Canvas` and control its position using the attached `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties or, using your current approach, use the `Margin` property to position it inside the `Grid`.

Here is an example.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var margin = ellipse.Margin;
    ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(margin.Left, margin.Top + 10, margin.Right, margin.Bottom);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="GrFrame">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Move down" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have sorted out with the TranslateTransform class after all, but at first I did try the canvas way and I could not access the Left nor Top Properties dynamically.

Comment: So you didn't try my example or found it helpful? Or what is your question?

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer What you probably missed was how to set attached properties in code. There are static getter and setter methods like `Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, x);` You should however ignore the Margin suggestion. That is not how absolute positioning is supposed to be done. Canvas.Left/Top or a TranslateTransform are certainly the appropriates approaches for you.